# Insert query where table name is textbox text

Tags: c#, sql, textbox

I have a problem in button1 click event of inserting data into a table which table name be determined by whatever text is in textbox1

Should mean something like that:

```
tablename = textbox1.text;

sql = "INSERT INTO tablename ([itemserial], [itemname], [itemcount],[itemimage]) VALUES (@itemserial, @itemname, @itemcount, @itemimage)";
```

Comment: do you just need to put the textbox text in the string? With C# 6 you can simply write: sql = $"INSERT INTO {tablename} ([itemserial],[itemname],[itemcount],[itemimage])VALUES(@itemserial,@itemname,@itemcount,@itemimage)"; [click here for string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a textbox containing the name of your table is challenging because you should add extra care in handling this value. You should implement some kind of checking on this textbox value. A possible solution is to check against your database schema if the table typed by your user really exists.

You don't tell us which database system are you using so I will show an example using Sql Server

```
string tableName = textbox1.text;
using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(... connectionstring...))
{
    cnn.Open();
    DataTable dt = cnn.GetSchema("TABLES");
    DataRow[] rows = dt.Select("TABLE_NAME = '" + tableName + "'");
    if(rows.Length > 0)
    {
        // Now you are sure to have a valid table in your textbox
        // and could use the input value without risking an Sql Injection
        string sql = "INSERT INTO [" + tableName + "] ([itemserial]," + 
                     "[itemname],[itemcount],[itemimage]) " + 
                     "VALUES(@itemserial,@itemname,@itemcount,@itemimage)";

        .... the remainder of your code that use the query above....
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid name for your table");
```

Extending this approach you could change your TextBox to a ComboBox with ComboBoxStyle set to DropDownList (to block typing) and fill the ComboBox with the names returned by the GetSchema call above....

Comment: Over time, other tables that don't conform to the data format could be added and users could cause errors. I would favor a white list approach: List<string> allowedTables = new List<string>() { "Table1", "table2" }; ... if (allowedTables.contains(tableName) { // then build the sql string and do the insert }

Answer (score 2):

```
tablename = textbox1.text;

sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ([itemserial],[itemname],[itemcount],[itemimage])VALUES(@itemserial,@itemname,@itemcount,@itemimage)", tablename);
```

Although I would strongly recommend against this as it allows people to enter whatever they want into that textbox. Something like:

Robert; DROP TABLE Students;--

Which is discussed in more detail here:
[How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Comment: I don't understand why, if you know the danger of this solution, are you proposing this.

Comment: I answered his questions as fast as I could because I desperately needed upvotes to allow me to upvote and comment on other user's comments... which I have finally earned so I can now upvote your much more expansive answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like this

```
sql = "INSERT INTO "+tablename+" ([itemserial],[itemname],[itemcount],[itemimage]) VALUES (@itemserial,@itemname,@itemcount,@itemimage)";
```